# Does a curve violate the first postulate of Euclidean Geometry?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, axioms, curves

Do the definitions and properties of curve secant and tangent lead to the violation of the first postulate of Euclidean Geometry?

Comment: Why do you think they do?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the first postulate is that given any two points, there is a line which has them as endpoints; this has little to do with curves, so how could the definition violate that? Actually, a *definition* in itself cannot violate any statement at all. Even

> **Definition.** A pair of two points is called a *Jabberwocky* if there does not exist a line which has them as endpoint.

does not contradict the first postulate. However, using the first postulate we quickly arrive at

> **Theorem.** There is no Jabberwocky.

Comment: *Jabberwocky* ... excellent.

Comment: Is it possible to draw a straight line containing two adjacent points of a curve?